# Free memory from wrapped fortran code in python

Tags: python, memory-management, fortran, f2py

I have a really large fortran code that allocates a lot of resources that I wrapped into python (most recent version) using f2py and it works great in principle.
(I get a .so file that I import into my python package.)
The problem occurs when I start the fortran code (by call) again later in python, as I get a lot of errors like:

```
Fortran runtime error: Attempting to allocate already allocated variable NAME
```

Is there a way from the python side to free all resources associated to the fortran call after it is done?

Basically, I want to be able to have a fresh new start after the code is finished executing.
Sorry in advance if this has been asked before, but I could not find it.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How about checking for allocation status every time you enter the code and deallocating if necessary? Like `if (allocated(name)) deallocate(name); allocate(name(100))`

Comment: This sounds like a fortran code base issue, the code was probably written to be run once, you could get the same result taking the original main routine, adding a subroutine/end sub wrap and then calling it twice from a new main. Use kings idea or identify where the allocate is and where a new deallocate shoild be when its out of scope

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that the code base is really huge and has a lot of global allocatable arrays. It will take forever to find all of the variables. The only solution I found now is to start it as a child process with multiprocessing Pool which then deallocates all the memory of the process when it finishes. This solution is not really useful though in multiprocessor environments, where you then get flooded with new processes everytime this wrapped code is called.